# how can i query my crm data on datetime and ignore the time and just put condition on date?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, query-expressions

so i have this query condition below:

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("fns_enddate", ConditionOperator.Equal, today.ToLocalTime().AddDays(-1));
```

is there any way to ignore time of datetime field?

example:

I want this record to come whose  fns_endate is 03/05/2018 6:00 but it's not getting picked up by query because of time (6:00).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong `ConditionOperator`, to compare dates you should use the [On operator (Yesterday can be also used in your scenario)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.conditionoperator.aspx):

**ConditionOperator.On**

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.On, today.ToLocalTime().AddDays(-1));
```

**ConditionOperator.Yesterday**

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.Yesterday);
```